# Excel: How to copy specific cell data (zip codes) into a new column

Tags: excel

I have two columns of cells that have irregularly formatted addresses.

I need:

1) just the zip codes to be copied into a new column;

2) the rows that do not contain zip codes to be either highlighted or empty so that I can easily identify which ones are missing.

This seems like it would be simple to do, but I can't figure out how to have Excel just find all instances of 5 consecutive numbers. Currently they are formatted as text so that the zero's are displayed. Any help greatly appreciated.

[Here's what it would be to start with:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k0UmB.png)
[image]

[Here's what it would look like when done (highlighting optional):](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N2dpM.png)
[image]

Comment: This is a perfect task for `Regular Expressions`. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another approach to what Zoff Dino wrote is to break it out a bit as shown below:

1. In cell C3 enter the formula you see in the formula bar
2. Drag that down the row set and over 1 column (so it runs for column B as well)
3. In column use this formula: `=IF(AND(C3="",D3=""),"",IF(C3="",D3,C3))` and drag it down.

This will account for all possible situations you have shown and not error out on you (unless other patterns emerge).

[image]

You can then use conditional formatting to highlight the rows with no zip code as shown in the picture:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You don't have Regular Expression in normal Excel. You would have to go into VBA to do that. However, for your case, there's an easy pattern: notice how the zip code is after the *last* space, and it's always 5 digits long? The challenge then become finding the index of this last space and extract the 5 characters that follow it. It will be clearer if you split them into 2 formula

```
// C3 (index of last space character):
=FIND("|",SUBSTITUTE(B3," ","|",LEN(B3)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(B3," ",""))))

// D3, the 5 characters after that.
// Return an empty string if the address doesn't match the pattern
=IFERROR(MID(B3,C3+1,5),"")
```

Comment: The formula in C3 there is a good one to know - first take the total length of a cell. Then take the length of the cell if you replace all instances of one character (say, " ") with nothing. Find the difference between those numbers.This tells you how many times that character appears. Then, use SUBSTITUTE to replace the nth instance of that character with any character that doesn't normally get used (say, "|"). Now, you can use FIND (or SEARCH) to determine where in a cell that "|" exists. In this case, you can then use the formula in D3, to pick up the 5 characters starting *after* the "I".

Comment: good formulas and method, but it will have some serious errors if just applied as is